# Bootstrap Mobile css is working only when you scroll Down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having weired issue. I am loading the Search form using Ajax. The css is applying properly. Only issue is in Bottom margin. The Bottom Margin apply when you scroll down in mobile view

When you load the form in ajax in mobile view

[image]

And when you scroll down in mobile, the bottom margin automatically applies.

[image]

I dont know what is happening

My code is

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 no-margin manage_boot" >   
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 no-padding search_title" >Gender:</div>
                        <div class="selector col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8 no-padding">
                             <!-- select box -->
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <!--Nationality-->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 no-margin manage_boot" >   
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 no-padding search_title" >Nationality:</div>
                        <div class="selector col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8 no-padding">
                             <!-- select box -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

My Ajax code is

```
$.ajax({
            url:'<?= SUB_URL ?>/services_html/more_advance_search',
            type:'post',
            data:{where_condition:1},
            success:function (data) {                
                $('#search_collapse').html(data);
```

Comment: Can you post your ajax code here ??

Comment: $.ajax({
         url:'<?= SUB_URL ?>/services_html/more_advance_search',
         type:'post',
         data:{where_condition:1},
         success:function (data) {           
    $('#search_collapse').html(data);

Comment: Can you post what you are getting into that data variable during ajax success because it might contain something which might be breaking your style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the css "row" along the bootstrap Css has fixed the issue

```
<div class="form-group row col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 no-margin manage_boot" >   
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 no-padding search_title" >Gender:</div>
                        <div class="selector col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8 no-padding">
                             <!-- select box -->
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <!--Nationality-->
                    <div class="form-group row col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 no-margin manage_boot" >   
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 no-padding search_title" >Nationality:</div>
                        <div class="selector col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8 no-padding">
                             <!-- select box -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
```